# Without redux devtool not working the app and error showing Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply') in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I am going to Build the React project the following error displays in the terminal and homepage blank.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')`

This is the code in the `redux` index file.

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import userReducer from './user/reducer';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['user'],
  blacklist: [],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, allReducers);

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export let persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Comment: please put all your code

Comment: the code I put from the index.js file. Do you mean the full project?

Comment: @MdJeweleIslam the code where this exception gets thrown from would probably be most useful